# How to have different colormaps for different columns in the same Heatmaps table using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

> I want to make a heatmap using different colors for only two columns in a heatmap. I was able to do it using two different pgfplotstables, i.e, two different heatmaps. But, i wan't to know whether i can do it using only one pgfplots table and changing the properties of colors only for the last two rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[font=small,compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries\color{darkblue}}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\lhead{Parent Feedback Report}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Kaddy.co}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{.55in}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2mm}}

\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                \begingroup
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]%
                    {\value}%
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\hfill
\resizebox{2.2in}{3.94in}{\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    font=\fontsize{6}{15}\selectfont,
    /pgfplots/colormap={blackwhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(255,170,0)},
    color cells={min=1,max=2323,textcolor=black},
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    col sep=comma,
    row sep=crcr,
]{
SA,A,N\\
1819, 2043, 126\\
2067, 1587, 218\\
986, 2018, 655\\
1257, 2068, 424\\
1722, 1977, 212\\
1322, 2036, 445\\
1264, 2119, 466\\
1205, 1952, 467\\
1855, 1776, 250\\
1638, 2029, 239\\
1953, 1686, 254\\
2020, 1758, 140\\
1835, 1843, 229\\
1371, 2178, 287\\
}}
\resizebox{1.4in}{3.94in}{\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    font=\fontsize{6}{15}\selectfont,
    /pgfplots/colormap={blackwhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(255,0,0)},
    color cells={min=1,max=323,textcolor=black},
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    col sep=comma,
    row sep=crcr,
]{
D,SD\\
24, 3\\
55, 10\\
147, 33\\
61, 3\\
32, 7\\
102, 17\\
60, 11\\
252, 54\\
55, 8\\
58, 8\\
33, 10\\
23, 3\\
41, 9\\
51, 4\\
}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the `pgfplotstable` manual, Section "From Input Data To Output Tables: Data Processing", this needs to be done by

> If you need to apply such content­based operations on specific rows,
>   you have to write code of sorts "if `\pgfplotstablerow` = generate
>   content differently".

It seems as if this quite complicated and requires a deep understanding of how TeX and pgfkeys works.

Here is an approach which should address your use-case and simplify the reconfiguration of content based on row indices:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2mm}}

\pgfplotstableset{
    /color cells/min/.initial=0,
    /color cells/max/.initial=1000,
    /color cells/textcolor/.initial=,
    color cells/.code={%
        \pgfqkeys{/color cells}{#1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{%
            postproc cell content/.code={%
                \begingroup
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}\value
                \ifx\value\empty
                \endgroup
                \else
                \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\value}%
                \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
                \let\value=\pgfmathresult
                \pgfplotscolormapaccess
                    [\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/min}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/color cells/max}]%
                    {\value}%
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/colormap name}}%
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\typesetvalue
                \pgfkeysgetvalue{/color cells/textcolor}\textcolorvalue
                \toks0=\expandafter{\typesetvalue}%
                \xdef\temp{%
                    \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{%
                        @cell content={%
                            \noexpand\cellcolor[rgb]{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfmathresult}%
                            \ifx\textcolorvalue\empty
                            \else
                                \noexpand\color{\textcolorvalue}%
                            \fi
                            \the\toks0 %
                        }%
                    }%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \temp
                \fi
            }%
        }%
    },
    %
    % A new style which allows to modify how cell content is assigned.
    % Unfortunately, assignment of cell content cannot be done by
    % means of "every row" and its friends -- we have to modify
    % 'postproc cell content' to alter it.
    % Usage:
    %   @content options for rows={<row index list>}{<options to apply>}
    % where
    %   <row index list> is a comma-separated list of row indices.
    %   Negative indices count backwards:
    %
    % Example:
    %   @content options for rows={0,3,-1}{<options to apply>}
    @content options for rows/.style 2 args={
         postproc cell content/.add code={%
            \def\isInInputList{0}%
            \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \II in {#1} {%
                \ifnum\II<0
                    % allow negative arguments:
                    \count0=\II
                    \advance\count0 by\pgfplotstablerows
                    \edef\II{\the\count0 }%
                \fi
                %
                \ifnum\II=\pgfplotstablerow\relax
                    \def\isInInputList{1}%
                \fi
            }%
            %\message{checking row \pgfplotstablerow/\pgfplotstablerows\space matches #1...^^J}%
            \if1\isInInputList%
                \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
            \fi
         }{},
    },
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    font=\fontsize{6}{15}\selectfont,
    % defines (and activates) a color map named "special":
    /pgfplots/colormap={special}{color=(white) color=(black)},
    %
    % defines and activates the colormap to use for all cases:
    /pgfplots/colormap={CM}{color=(white) rgb255=(255,170,0)},
    color cells={min=1,max=2323,textcolor=black},
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    col sep=comma,
    row sep=crcr,
    %
    % reconfigure a couple of rows:
    @content options for rows={3,-1,-2}{/pgfplots/colormap name=special},
]{
SA,A,N\\
1819, 2043, 126\\
2067, 1587, 218\\
986, 2018, 655\\
1257, 2068, 424\\
1722, 1977, 212\\
1322, 2036, 445\\
1264, 2119, 466\\
1205, 1952, 467\\
1855, 1776, 250\\
1638, 2029, 239\\
1953, 1686, 254\\
2020, 1758, 140\\
1835, 1843, 229\\
1371, 2178, 287\\
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I introduced a new key `@content options for rows={<row index list>}{<options to apply>}`, see the inline-comments for details.

Note that the leading `@` is actually unnecessary... I added it because I find the option useful; perhaps I will add it to `pgfplotstable` eventually (and then I would like to reuse the name without the `@`).